# Remove parent div if date expired by class and not id

Tags: jquery, date

Trying to show/hide div if date has expired by class and not id.

Html

```
<div class="test">
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2022-09-14" />
</div>

<div class="test">
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2018-09-11" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
window.setInterval(function() {

  var current = new Date();
  var expiry = new Date($('.date-input').val());

  if (current.getTime() > expiry.getTime()) {
    $('.date-input').parents('div').hide();

  } else if (current.getTime() < expiry.getTime()) {
    $('.date-input').parents('div').show();
  }

}, 0);
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/qhgrtwzm/832/

In this example, both divs are displayed, as the first date has not yet expired. How do I apply show/hide to each individual div without using id?

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit - In case anyone was wondering how I was going to use this code... I want to make events disappear when the date expires. See: https://www.citychurchchristchurch.co.nz/events

Comment: $('.date-input') returns an array. you have to loop through the array and process each element individually.

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/rLkgj0ha/4/

Comment: Well done thanks Jules!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.setInterval(function() {

  var current = new Date();

  $('.date-input').each(function(){
    var jqDiv = $(this).parent('div');
    if (current > new Date($(this).val())) {
      jqDiv.hide();
    } else {
      jqDiv.show();
    }
  });

}, 0);
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

how about use the filter function.

run snippet below

```js
window.setInterval(function() {
$(".date-input" ).show();
$( ".date-input" )
  .filter(function( index ) {
    return new Date() >  new Date($(this).val()) 
  }).parent('div').hide();
}, 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2022-09-14" />
</div>

<div class="test">
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2018-09-11" />
</div>
```